# File sharing fails for non-Google applications

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I use [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to share my app's images. While it works perfectly for file sharing via gmail, hangouts, drive etc, I can not share file via non-Google apps ie WhatsApp, Viber.

[FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) in Androidmanifest

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="<package.name>.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
```

filepath.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path path="" name="export" />
</paths>
```

Method for sharing file

```
/**
 * Static method to export charts data
 *
 * @param mContext object context
 * @param view     chart to be converted into image
 * @throws IOException
 **/
public static void exportChartAsPng(Context mContext, View view) throws IOException {
    File baseDir = mContext.getFilesDir();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");

    String fileName = "chart-" + df.format(calendar.getTimeInMillis()) + ".png";
    String filePath = baseDir.toString() + File.separator + fileName;
    File chartFile = new File(filePath);

    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(chartFile);
    getBitmapFromView(view).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();

    try {
        Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                mContext,
                "<package.name>.fileprovider",
                chartFile);


        Intent sendIntent = new Intent("<package.name>.ACTION_RETURN_FILE");
        if (fileUri != null) {
            // Grant temporary read permission to the content URI
            sendIntent.addFlags(
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
        sendIntent.setType("image/png");
        mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, mContext.getString(R.string.share)));

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e("File Selector",
                "The selected file can't be shared: " +
                        chartFile.getName());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Check LogCat for error messages from the other apps. My guess it that you are dealing with apps that make invalid assumptions about `content://` `Uri` values. [My `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#usage-legacycompatcursorwrapper) clears up some of these problems. It is fairly easy to [add it to an existing `FileProvider` implementation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider).